# Flex4 Button is covered by runtime graphic and is unusable

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

Newbie here,

I have a skinned button at x=47 y=126 which is later "covered" by a .png that loads dynamically.  Once the .png loads, the button disappears.  How can I tell Flash Builder 4 to place the .png behind the button so that it is always clickable.  FYI: if I move the button away from the graphic, it works just fine, but, for design purposes, I really would like it to stay where it is.

Thanks,

Jason M.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try giving the button a depth value of 1 or higher.

`"Spark containers order their items based on their depth property, with the lowest depth in the back, and the higher in the front.Items with the same depth value appear in the order they are added to the container."`

```
<s:Button x="47" y="126" depth="1" skin="customSkin"/>
```

Conversely you could add a smaller depth to the .png, or if you are drawing them in the same container change the order they are in there. (From the quote above on depth)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have an image as a background for your button you should place it behind button the following way:

```
<s:Group>
    <s:BitmapImage />
    <s:Button />
</s:Group>
```

I suppose your case is the following:

```
<s:Group>
    <s:Button />
    <s:BitmapImage />
</s:Group>
```